# Регулярное выражение выбрать только буквы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как выбрать только Русские буквы?

из формы отправляется строчка (имя) с данными, строка должна содержать слово написанное русскими буквами и не содержать больше никаких символов. В случае соответствия условиям, скрипты выполняют дальнейшую работу с ней (не принципиально в рамках вопроса). Иначе выводится сообщение об ошибке. например: "поле имя должно содержать только русские буквы"

какой стандарт выражений не знаю, но проверка на номер телефона написана вот так: `^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$`
а вот выбрать только русские буквы не получилось.

пробовал:

```
[А-Яа-я]
[А-Я|а-я]
[А-Я|а-я]\D
[А-Яа-я]
[А-Яа-я^d]
\w\D
```

Знаю что задача простая для знающих, но елки-палки, посмотрел несколько уроков с практическими заданиями, посмотрел гугл, попробовал вариант, и то что сверху это еще не полные список уже со счета сбился

такой вариант `[А-Яа-я]` проверяет почти как надо: если я пишу любые символы кроме кириллицы, выдает ошибку, но как только впишу русские - ошибок нет.

Comment: Вопрос переформулируйте, а то сейчас не понятно: куда вы их выбрать хотите? в каком виде? что на входе? что ожидаете на выходе?

Comment: Касательно последнего "если" желательно пример. В какой кодировке работаете? Какой стандарт выражений(или ЯП)?

Comment: `/[а-я]/ui` может подойти

Comment: @vp_arth дополнил вопрос

Comment: какой язык кстати?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> поле имя должно содержать только русские буквы

Нужно добавить якоря начала и конца строки:

```
/^а-яё$/ui
```

Демонстрация в js:

```js
{
  let res = [
    'Алексей',
    'Лёша',
    'ЛюдиX',
    'X-фактор'
  ].reduce((res, name)=> (res[name] = /^[а-яё]+$/ui.test(name), res), {});
  console.log(res);
}
```